# Concavity function

Tags: analysis, optimization

Suppose we have a function $g(x)$ which is concave in $x$. Is it still the case that $g(1-F(x))$ is concave with $F(x)$ a cdf? I have problems with (dis)proving it.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: What does cdf mean?

Comment: cumulative distribution function

Answer (score 0):

If you check the rules for concavity of compositions, you will find statements involving monotonicity of $g$ and convexity of $F$. The statement is currently clearly false for $g(x)=x$ and any cdf.

Comment: Thanks! What properties should $g$ satisfy in order to have $g(1-F(x)$ concave in $x$?

Comment: Just check the second derivative.

Comment: So I have to check g''(1-F(x))f(x)+ (df/dx)g'(1-F(x))<0? I need to find a particular form of $g$ but it is quite hard.. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Right. I don't think there is one $g$ that works for all cdfs. If $g$ can depend on (the inverse of) $F$ it would be easier.

Comment: Yes, that is allowed. I'm mainly interested in normal cdfs. Do you have any idea? Thanks!